# Google App data store and GQL in Django

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

Is there a way to use GQL and Google App engine data store with Django? If yes then how to use it, I have searched on web but I am unable to find any satisfying answers to this problem?

Comment: It looks like there's docs here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django - are these what you're looking for?

Comment: of course you can, but why would you want to? Perhaps this is what you want, http://django-nonrel.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of both cloud-sql and django-nonrel we dont use GQL as query language. They use SQL and MySql. But I wanted to use GQL in Django. So when I looked at documentation of Google app data store and GQL for google app engine webapp2 I found out that it has nothing to do with webapp2, instead it was for python. So only thing which I changed to make it working for Django was the method of rendering the request.